# Binary to decimal conversion(positional notation method) using for_each loop c++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, binary

I'm using positional notation method convert binary to decimal and its different i guess nobody has tried it yet i guess, and in this I'm using for_each loop
Here are some steps:

- store binary as string

-take out one digit at a time from string using for_each loop and do operation.

```
int main(void)
{
string input;
cout << "Enter string of binary digits " ;
cin >> input ;
for_each(input.begin(), input.end(),bitodec);
cout << "Decimal equivalent is  " << u << endl;
 system("PAUSE");
}
```

[here is full code](http://ideone.com/pePVdm)

There is logical error.

Comment: There are easier ways, like using [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: You did not really ask a question, but since i presume you would like to know about your compiler error, std::for_each is declared in <algorithm>

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking?

Comment: @P0W yes, take out one digit and determine if its 0 or 1 if its one then according to positional notation method the position number will be power of base 2, after solving add them all and that will be result in decimal

Comment: I'm just implementing my thoughts @JoachimPileborg I'm gonna try this too and will let you know.

Comment: @PhilippLenk No there is no any compiler error, there is logical error at my end.

Comment: @Roman there is logical error

Comment: @user2917063 The compiler error i mentioned in my comment and answer was copied from the code you linked, it is right there ;-)
One logical error is the one i mentioned in my answer, your bitodec function does not use your global u, but a new, temporary one

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly it is you are asking, since you did not state a question. I presume, however, that you would like to know why you get the compiler error:

```
prog.cpp:13:48: error: ‘for_each’ was not declared in this scope
  for_each(input.begin(), input.end(),bitodec);
```

(It would have been nice if this was included in the question)

You get this error because you try to use std::for_each, which was not declared in your program. It is defined in the "algorithm" header, so to fix this problem, you would have to add

```
#include <algorithm>
```

somewhere at the beginning of your file.

There are, however, some other problems with the complete code(which should really have been included in your question), for instance: Your global variable u is never modified, because you declare a new, temporary one in bitodec's if block and modify this one.

So, as Joachim Pileborg mentioned in the comments, it would be much easier(and apparently less error prone), to simply use std::stoi.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: I'm trying binary to decimal conversion with different approach(just implementing my thoughts i don't know it will always right or wrong approach), and encountering a logical error, its always giving 0 as answer in decimal.

Comment: @user2917063 I mentioned the reason for this in the answer, you never use your global variable u, your line "int u = pow(2.0, (int)y);" declares a new, temporary one, which exists only within the if-block ;-)

Comment: And if i declare it within block, it will display "input digits times" wrong answer, and initialize every time for_each loop runs.

Comment: Sorry, i dont really understand what you are trying, could you show some code?

Comment: That is a little worse than before, first, you still use the temporary u, if you dont want to create a new variable within the if block, write "u=..." instead of "int u=...". Furthermore, now you create a new (uninitialized) variable with each call of bitodec, so if you were to actually use it within the if block, its contents would be undefined

Comment: if i declare it within global scope its problem,and if i declare it within block scope its also a problem! *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation of `std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) says:

> Bitsets can be manipulated by standard logic operators and **converted to and from strings and integers**.

So using `std::bitset` is a simple way to achieve your goal. For example:

```
std::string bit_string = "110010";
std::bitset<8> b3(bit_string);       // [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0]
std::bitset<8> b4(bit_string, 2);    // [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
std::bitset<8> b5(bit_string, 2, 3); // [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```